# How to do vulnerability scanning of uploaded pdf files in .NET?

Tags: .net, security, pdf

I am working on an existing web application that accepts PDF files as a byte array. This is working fine from a functional perspective. Since file uploads can be a security problem, I want to analyse my files for vulnerabilities. A well known tool for this is [peedpf](https://github.com/jesparza/peepdf), which is also [available as a package for existing applications](https://pypi.org/project/peepdf/0.3.2/). However, this is python based and the web application that requires this functionality is based on .NET Framework so a .NET Framework based solution is highly preferred. In addition, some applications my web application communicates with are based on .NET Core so that could be an option too.

Logically, I need a peepdf alternative for .NET. What do I need to use? The .NET based packages for PDF reading I found online seem to focus on functional things (converting, comparing, reading text etc).

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion one the way to do is to wrap the peedf into a micro service and consume the REST call from your main application by passing in the path of the uploaded PDF file over a shared drive which the other microservice has access to. It is highly unlikely that you will find a .NET / .NET Core equivalent unless you want to port peedf to .NET Core.